# Ajax not posting to data to classic asp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I'm working with two classic asp pages. In the first page, I have a modal dialog box with a button that when clicked, is suppose to send data to the second asp page.

The problem is that I'm getting a "success" callback when it's ran but that data is not being posted to the second page.

Here is the first page:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#SendNegAdj").click(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title:"Send Negative Adjustment",
            width: 400,
            height: 200,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Send:
                function(){
                    $.post("http://test.asp",
                    {libid:"test"});
    console.log(libid);

                    //$(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Close:
                function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
})
```

And here is where the data is supposed to be posted to:

```
<% Dim test
test = Request("libid")
Response.Write test
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code first of all uses `$.post()` to make a POST request with Ajax. If it gets a successful response, it ignores the data in that response and runs `location.replace` to make a *completely new* GET request to the same URL.

The browser then displays the response to the GET response.

If you want to make a POST request and display the result as a new page, then submit a form. Don't use Ajax.

Comment: the location.replace is only for testing purposes. The final result that I would like is that the data is sent to the page without invoking a page refresh. Shoud've mentioned that in my post. Sorry.

Comment: Then you need to use the data you get back instead of using `location.replace`. As pointed out in this answer, `location.replace` will discard the data you got when making the POST request.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Request.Form()`:

```
<% Dim test
  test = Request.Form("libid")
  Response.Write test
%>
```